# Missing images when opening a wpf window from a windows forms application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to open a WPF-window from a Windows Forms application. The Windows loads, and the functionality of the WPF-window is as it should be, but the images i added to some buttons in my WPF-window do not get shown. The build action property of the images has been set to "Resource". I am loading from the WinForm App with this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var wpfwindow = new WPF.View.MainWindow();
    wpfwindow.Show();
}
```

What can i do to solve the problem?

Comment: Does everything open properly when you run WPF-window itself?

Comment: Yes it does, when i run the WPF-window as startup project

Answer (score 0):

In WinForms there is no WPF `System.Windows.Application` active, therefore 'pack' uri prefix is not recognized and resource images referenced as 'pack://some image uri' cannot be loaded.

Either register uri prefix:

```
if (!UriParser.IsKnownScheme("pack"))
{
    UriParser.Register(new GenericUriParser
        (GenericUriParserOptions.GenericAuthority), "pack", -1);
}
```

or try to create an instance of [Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class

Comment: Thank you. Im not new to WPF, but i gotta admit i don't know where to put the you posted? Where do i registrer the prefix?

Comment: There are 2 ways: 1. At application startup (recommeded). 2. immediately before showing WPF window.